# How to call a method in fragment from a service?

Tags: android, service, fragment, job-scheduling

In my app, I am using `JobScheduler` for running a task in a period of time with `setPeriodic` function.

How can I call a method in Fragment from the Scheduler Service?

WeeklyJobService.java

```
  @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        doBackgroundWork(params);

        return true;
    }

    private void doBackgroundWork(JobParameters params) {

        // Here I want to call a method in Fragment
        jobFinished(params, false);
        }).start();
    }
```

TopWeekFragment.java

For example let the function be adding two numbers and setting the value in a TextView

```
 private void sum()
    {
        int i=22, j=10;
        textview.setText(String.valueOf(i+j));
    }
```

JobSchedule Function

```
private void scheduleJob(View v) {
        @SuppressLint("JobSchedulerService")
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), WeeklyJobService.class);
        JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(123, componentName)
                .setRequiresCharging(true)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .setPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000)
                .build();

        JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getActivity().getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        int resultCode = scheduler.schedule(info);
        if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduled");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduling failed");
        }
    }
```

The concept is, for every periodic time, function sum must be repeated.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Since the fragment is unlikely to exist, you have an architecture problem. You are asking your work to occur every 15 minutes, forever. Your app will not be in the foreground forever.

Comment: Ohh yeah i understand that. Or is there a way where the fragment gets updated when user clicks on it?

Comment: Instead can i use alarm manager?

Comment: No, in that it does not change the problem.You will need to do something that is more "loosely coupled", where you make information from the job available to the rest of your app, but that you do not assume that your UI exists. Your job can talk to some sort of singleton repository, which can then publish an update that your UI can subscribe to if the UI is around. Event buses, RxJava, `LiveData`, and `Flow` from Kotlin's coroutines are all possible solutions here.